# how to merge table cells from redefined environments

Tags: tables, macros, environments, multicolumn, documentclass-writing

I am writing my CV and i have a problem for merging table cells. The table is defined in the new latex environment "experience", written on the modelcv_dbg.cls file as shown below

```
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\newenvironment{experience}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|l|}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\experienceitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.88\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
    \midrule
%   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#4}
}
```

Here is the example of calling the environment experience.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{modelcv_dbg} % a4paper for A4

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{ Professional Experiences}

\begin{experience} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    %\experienceitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}

    \experienceitem{2018-2019}
        {phd student.}
        {University}
        {\emph{tasks} :
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item task 1.
                    \item task 2. 
                \end{itemize}
          \emph{Publication} : \\
                name1, name2, name2;
                 article title; book.
        }
\end{experience}
\end{document}
```

I would write the paragraph "{\emph{task}....}" onto 2 cells in the table defined in the "\experienceitem" command. I comment and uncomment some lines (see below) and i have got an runtime error.

```
\newcommand{\experienceitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.88\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\
%       #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#4}
}
```

how could i merge the cells in the last row of \newcommand{\experienceitem}?

Here is my sketch
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a sketch of the desired output to your question? Unfortunately I don't seem to understand what you mean with " write the paragraph "{\emph{task}....}" onto 2 cells in the table"  and "merge the cells in the last row".

Comment: Thanks @leandriis for your answer. I add a sketch on my previous publication.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are more satisfied with the following layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % a4paper for A4
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\newenvironment{experience}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|r|}}
{%
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\experienceitem}[4]{%
    #1& \textbf{#2} & {\footnotesize#3}\\%
    \multicolumn{3}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{#4}\\
}

\begin{document}

\section{ Professional Experiences}

\begin{experience} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    %\experienceitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}

    \experienceitem{2018-2019}
        {phd student.}
        {University}
        {\emph{tasks} :
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item task 1.
                    \item task 2. 
                \end{itemize}
          \emph{Publication} : \newline
                name1, name2, name2;
                 article title; book.}
\end{experience}
\end{document}
```

Side note: horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package are incompatible with vertical lines (See the small gap in the vertical line at the intersections).

To  remove the third vertical line, use `\begin{tabular}{|l|lr|}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot ......